# How to stretch to fit background image on live wallpaper

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I am trying to set the background of my live wallpaper so as to fit perfectly on screen. Current wallpaper size is 1024x1024, but only a part of the image  is appearing on my HTC Desire screen(size is 480 x 800).
Also, when i try to set an image of less than 480x800, the image doesn't stretch to fit the entire screen.

Is there any way by which this can be achieved so that the wallpaper fits perfectly atleast by height irrespective of screen size?

Here is my code for your reference-

```
private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 720;


@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
 final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
 return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}


@Override
public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {
 .
 .
 this.mBitmapBackgroundAtlas1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024);
 this.mFaceBackgroundRegion1 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapBackgroundAtlas1, this, "bg1.jpg", 0, 0);
 this.mBitmapBackgroundAtlas1.load();
 .
 .
}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
 this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
 .
 .
 mScene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(new Sprite(0, 0, mFaceBackgroundRegion1, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager())));
 .
 .
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok...found the answer. Posting it for those who are also looking for same.

You can override the method, onSurfaceChanged which has width and height as arguments. This gives the screen width/height of your device.

You can use this values to scale the image to your requirement.

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
 this.screenWidth=width;
 this.screenHeight=height;
}
```